# Apex Data Transfer Object. Deserializing data

Tags: apex

I am new to Apex and SF and I have to manage some errors from an 3rd party API we are calling. I have been using DTO with very simple response objects and the error response object we get back has one more level.

JSON response from API:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "File couldn't be downloaded: main_panel"
    }
}
```

DTO file:

```
public class CreateCadRequestError {
        public string error;
        public CreateCadRequestErrorMessage message;
    }
    
    public class CreateCadRequestErrorMessage {
        public string message;
    }
```

Apex class deserializing data

```
class SoloConnector {
    resp = makeNetworkCall()...
    SoloDTO.CreateCadRequestError resp = ( SoloDTO.CreateCadRequestError )JSON.deserialize( response.getBody(), SoloDTO.CreateCadRequestError.class );
    System.debug('resp: ' + resp.error + resp.message);

}
```

I am getting an error

```
illegal value for primitive
```

I assume its my DTO class and not being able to serialize the data. Any suggetsions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DTO is not structured correctly. It should read:

```
public class CreateCadRequestError {
    public CreateCadRequestErrorMessage error;
}
public class CreateCadRequestErrorMessage {
    public string message;
}
```

The [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) app can help you properly structure your DTO classes given a sample JSON input.